# Run MVC3 through a website project template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

Is it possible to run MVC 3 through a website project template or you have to convert your existing WebForms website project to web application and then do the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run MVC 3 through a website project template

Yes, it is possible to use a WebSite for an ASP.NET MVC application but not recommended. In order to make it work you will have to put your controllers and models into non-standard locations such as the `App_Code` directory so you will end up with something horrible at the end. Something that's not worth migrating towards and that you will have to convert to a web application later. You will be doing twice the work.

So do the conversion to a web application first. Or depending on the *quality of the code* of this existing website, it's probably not worth doing any migrations but starting from scratch a new ASP.NET MVC application and adding progressively functionality from this site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had that in mind but wanted a second opinion!